# RSpec testing devise controller actions, DELETE failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I'm using RSpec to test my implementation of the mixture of Devise and the `simple_token_authentication` gem.

---

I using `devise_for` to tell Devise where to look for my sessions controller ([source](https://github.com/earlymarket/CoPosition/blob/master/config/routes.rb#L8)).

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: { 
    registrations: 'users/devise/registrations',
    sessions: 'users/devise/sessions'
  }
```

---

In my sessions controller, I invoke a custom method if the request has a specific header ([source](https://github.com/earlymarket/CoPosition/blob/master/app/controllers/users/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L8)).

```
def create
  req_from_coposition_app? ? respond_with_auth_token : super
end

def destroy
  req_from_coposition_app? ? destroy_auth_token : super
end
```

---

I have a test that ensures the user can get an auth token.
The request works as expected ([source](https://github.com/earlymarket/CoPosition/blob/master/spec/controllers/users/sessions_controller_spec.rb#L20)).

```
it "should be able to sign in" do
  request.headers["X-Secret-App-Key"] = "this-is-a-mobile-app" 
  request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  post :create, 
    user: {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    }, 
    format: :json

  expect(res_hash[:email]).to eq user.email
  expect(res_hash[:authentication_token]).to eq user.authentication_token
end
```

---

Next, I'd like to test signing out (destroying the auth key).
I am trying to use the following code:

```
it "should be able to sign out" do
  token_before = user.authentication_token
  request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  request.headers["X-Secret-App-Key"] = "this-is-a-mobile-app"
  request.headers["X-User-Token"] = token_before
  delete :destroy, nil, format: :json
  expect(user.reload.authentication_token).to_not eq token_before
end
```

However, the `Users::Devise::SessionsController#destroy` is never hit.
`response.status` is `302`, and

```
response.body
#=> "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://test.host/\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
```

I have checked rake routes, formatted the request in different ways, and checked that the `delete` method wasn't being messed with anywhere. I am completely at loss as to why `post :create` works, but `delete :destroy` doesn't hit the action.

Comment: The `simple_token_authentication` README example shows the X-User-Token *and* X-User-Email fields in the header. Perhaps you need to supply X-User-Email as well?

Answer (score 1):

You're not fooling the before filter on line 4 here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

Devise thinks no one is signed in and is bouncing you away from the destroy action. Skip it, stub it, trick it.